# How to disable Minew's e7 beacon to send "Unknown" type?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

in our project, we use Minew's gateway G1 and E7 beacon.
We configured the gateway to upload both "IBeacon" and "Unknown" data as we want to monitor both beacons and other devices(mobiles,...). Also, we enabled "Filter duplicate data" as we believe it returns the latest data per MAC address from the interval window.
Then we configured beacon to use only 2 frames, "IBeacon" and "DeviceInfo". As far as we understand, "IBeacon" is supposed to be picked up by the gateway, while "DeviceInfo" broadcasts pickable info for the beacon to be detectable(via the beaconset+ app). The remaining frames are left empty.

And here comes the problem.
 The data which the gate sends to our backend app contains "IBeacon" **or** "Unknown" "type". It never sends none or both of the types. This seems to be because of the order in which the data are received by the gate and "Filter duplicate data" gate setting.

**So, my question is**:

- How to configure the beacon/gate to consistently send "IBeacon" type for beacons and "Unknown" type for the unknown devices?

**What have we tried**:

- when we set the gate to upload only "IBeacon" data, it consistently sends the correct beacon data (including UUID, minor and major). However, the "Unknown" devices are obviously not detected

Answer (score 0):

For Model G1-C version V3.1.3 you can configured a Data Filtering like is shown in the following screen snippet:

[image]

Comment: I am also trying to locate this data from minew ibeacon but it seems that it is not sending through the gateway. Did you find any solution of that and can you please share what exactly the device info frame rawdata?